# Finding duplicate value in a row (2D array)

Tags: c

I would like to know how to find duplicate values in the 1st row of my 2d array.

I thought that by setting `array[0][0] == array[i][j]`, it would check if the `array[0][0]` equals to the number of `array[0][rest of the column]`. But my code is just popping up my try again message whenever I put my first value.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
void main(void)
{
int array[2][5];
int i, j, l, k;

printf("\Please enter 10 values\n");
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &array[i][j]);

        for (k = 0; k < 2; k++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < 5; l++)
            {
                while (array[0][0] == array[i][j])
                {
                    printf("You entered 2 identical numbers in the first row, try again:\n");
                    scanf("%i", &array[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well one problem is that you can't check for duplicates when you have only entered one value, but your code does exactly that. You need to rethink your logic. Personally I would simplify. First enter the array, then check for duplicates, if there are any get the user to reenter the entire array.

Comment: If you were asking a question specific to the Visual C++ compiler, then the "visual-c++" tag would be appropriate. However, you seem to be asking a question about the language C which is not specific to any compiler. Therefore, only the tag "c" is appropriate. So you set it correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this isn't the fastest algorithm but it works because of the small length
int check_duplicates(int arr[], int len) {
    // iterate through the array
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // only need to check to the right
        // since the left elements have been checked previously
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                // there's a duplicate, return
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // no duplicates found
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int array[2][5];
    int i, j, l, k;

    printf("Please enter 10 values\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            scanf("%i", &array[i][j]);
            // a duplicate has been found
            if (check_duplicates(array[0], j + 1)) {
                printf("You entered a duplicate, try again.\n");
                // undo one loop to read back into that position
                i --;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```